# Get a random search result from Amazon CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

My query is like:

```
/2013-01-01/search?q=(and author:'william' category:'Videos')&q.parser=structured&expr.random=_rand&return=_all_fields&size=1
```

and returns a video. However, I want a random videoId on every request.

Using the expression `&expr.random=_rand;` I'm unable to fetch a random result and I have failed to find any solution in documentation.

How can I get a random search result on every request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this through pagination by setting the `start` param to a random value from 0 to `hits.found` and requesting `size=1`:

```
search?q=matchall&q.parser=structured&size=1&start={yourRandomNumber}
```

If the number of documents in your index is fluctuating, you'll need to make 2 queries: one to get the max number of results (comes back as `hits.found`), and another to retrieve the random result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with your answer but i have little confusion about performance on making double request as my number of document is unknown.

Answer (score 7):

The CloudSearch docs are quite lacking. I needed something similar and came up short with Google so I just started guessing by applying what I already knew about Solr and I found a solution:

```
/2013-01-01/search?q=what&sort=_rand_1 desc
```

Note that _rand will also work however after the first search it will always return the same results which is actually ideal if you need to paginate through a random result set (it works the same way in Solr). So, to get random results every time you need to randomly generate an _something and append it to _rand.

Comment: Just to complete the comment in c# I have done this part of code : var request = new SearchRequest() { ...  Sort = string.Format("_rand_{0} desc", DateTime.Now.Ticks) .... };